# Generate nighttime average of weather variables in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have hourly weather data from a regional airport in this format:

| date_time | temp_c | cloud_cover |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-13 10:53:00 | 14.45 | 75 |
| 2022-08-13 11:53:00 | 14.42 | 50 |
| 2022-08-14 00:53:00 | 14.39 | 50 |
| 2022-08-14 01:53:00 | 14.35 | 50 |

I have data for all 24 hours, but would like to generate averages of weather variables for only the nighttime period, from 19:00:00 to 07:00:00 UTC.

I'm unsure how to generate these as the nighttime periods span two dates (the example data above illustrates this). I've tried subset() and aggregate() functions without any luck. My desired output would not be a running average but would look like this:

| date | avg_temp | avg_cloud |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-13 | 14.40 | 56.25 |
| 2022-08-14 | 15.00 | 55.38 |

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

An example using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)

isBetween <- function(date, beg, end) 
  hm(beg) - hm(format(date, "%H:%M")) < 0 | 
  hm(end) - hm(format(date, "%H:%M")) > 0
```

with given example

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0 reframe, < 1.1.0 summarize

df %>% 
  mutate(betw = isBetween(ymd_hms(date_time), "19:00", "07:00")) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(betw != lag(betw, default=T))) %>% 
  filter(betw) %>% 
  reframe(date = as.Date(format(mean(date_time), "%Y-%m-%d")), 
          across(temp_c:cloud_cover, ~ mean(.x))) %>% 
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  date       temp_c cloud_cover
  <date>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2022-08-14   14.4          50
```

with extended data set

```
df_e %>% 
  mutate(betw = isBetween(ymd_hms(date_time), "19:00", "07:00")) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(betw != lag(betw, default=T))) %>% 
  filter(betw) %>% 
  reframe(date = as.Date(format(mean(date_time), "%Y-%m-%d")), 
          across(temp_c:cloud_cover, ~ mean(.x))) %>% 
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  date       temp_c cloud_cover
  <date>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2022-08-13   20.7        18.7
2 2022-08-15   20.4        45  
3 2022-08-15   10          68
```

##### extended data

```
df_e <- structure(list(date_time = structure(c(1660380780, 1660384380, 
1660405980, 1660409580, 1660413180, 1660416780, 1660452780, 1660456380, 
1660459980, 1660463580, 1660467180, 1660492380, 1660495980, 1660499580, 
1660503180, 1660531980, 1660535580, 1660539180, 1660542780, 1660546380, 
1660578780, 1660582380, 1660585980), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), temp_c = c(23L, 20L, 23L, 20L, 27L, 13L, 22L, 
26L, 23L, 10L, 14L, 20L, 19L, 25L, 11L, 25L, 24L, 17L, 18L, 11L, 
24L, 27L, 10L), cloud_cover = c(76L, 49L, 69L, 7L, 22L, 4L, 30L, 
31L, 73L, 93L, 25L, 85L, 43L, 73L, 13L, 4L, 75L, 60L, 48L, 65L, 
33L, 49L, 68L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
56L, 57L, 58L), class = "data.frame")
```